# FeatureCollection is not a valid type of discriminator Error

Tags: python, geojson, planet

I'm trying to pull in Planet data to visualise satellite imagery using Jupyter. I'm new to Python and I get an error like this:

```
{
 "field": {
  "filter.config.0.config.type": [
   {
    "message": "FeatureCollection is not a valid type for discriminator"
   },
   {
    "message": "u'FeatureCollection' is not one of ['Point', 'MultiPoint', 'LineString', 'MultiLineString', 'Polygon', 'MultiPolygon']"
   }
  ]
 },
 "general": []
}
```

My code snippet for drawing my API key is this :

```
import os
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


PLANET_API_KEY = os.environ.get("PL_API_KEY") 

item_type = "PSScene4Band"

search_request = {
  "interval": "day",
  "item_types": [item_type], 
  "filter": combined_filter
}

search_result = \
  requests.post(
    'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/stats',
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PLANET_API_KEY, ''),
    json=search_request)

print(json.dumps(search_result.json(), indent=1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pointing out your problem. The geometry filter of Planet Data API does not support `FeatureCollection`. It only supports `'Point', 'MultiPoint', 'LineString', 'MultiLineString', 'Polygon', 'MultiPolygon'`. [Here](https://developers.planet.com/docs/quickstart/searching-for-imagery/#select-an-area-of-interest-aoi) you can check a basic example.

As a workaround, you could loop throught your feature collection and apply the API call for every feature. Something like this should work:

```
results = []

for feature in geojson['features']:

  geometry_filter = {
    "type": "GeometryFilter",
    "field_name": "geometry",
    "config": feature
  }

  combined_filter.append(geometry_filter)

  search_result = \
  requests.post(
    'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/stats',
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PLANET_API_KEY, ''),
    json=search_request) 

  results.append(search_result)
```